# How to access cell given values in other columns

Tags: r

Suppose we have this data frame with 4 columns:

```
Subject Trial Before After
      1     1     10    16
      1     2     11    17
      1     3     12    18
      2     1     13    19
      2     2     14    20
      2     3     15    21
```

Assume there is at most one row with a given subject number and a trial number. Given a subject number and a trial number, how do I access the value in the `Before` column in the row with the given subject and trial number?

Thank you.

Comment: `subset(mydf, Subject == 1 & Trial == 3, select=Before)`? For example with sub 1 and trial 3

Comment: See `help(Logic)` and `help(Extract)`

Answer (score 3):

There are 342 ways, but one is with `subset`:

```
df <- head(mtcars)
df
#                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1

subset(df, cyl == 4 & disp == 108, select=mpg)
#            mpg
#Datsun 710 22.8
```

A few more

```
with(df, mpg[cyl == 4 & disp == 108])
#[1] 22.8

library(dplyr)
df %>% filter(cyl == 4 & disp == 108) %>% select(mpg)
#   mpg
#1 22.8

library(data.table)
setDT(df)[cyl == 4 & disp == 108, mpg]
#[1] 22.8
```

Comment: Precisely 342 ways?

Comment: I counted once. Long night

Answer (score 0):

With the data frame below, you would run two evaluations (one for each row) and combine the results with the `&` operator. This returns a vector of TRUE/FALSE values, which you can reduce to an index by using the `which()` function. You then apply that in a data frame row reference, and specify the column that you want to return from that row.

```
a = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2)
b = c(1,2,3,1,2,3)
c = c(10,11,12,13,14,15)
d = c(16,17,18,19,20,21)
e = data.frame(a,b,c,d)

e[which(e$a == 2 & e$b == 2), 'c']
```